# infoWindow is not shown in the center of the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Here is the code I'm using to show markers and infoWindows. It's working perfectly.

```
mapOptions = {
  zoom: zoom,
  center: getMyCompanyCoordinates,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map($(this)[0], mapOptions)

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
  createMarker = (company)->
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(company.latitude, company.longitude),
        map: map
      })

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ()->
        infowindow.setContent('content')
        infowindow.open(map,this)
      )
      return marker


  firstCompanyMarker = createMarker(companiesData[0])
  createMarker(companiesData[i]) for i in [1..companiesData.length-1] by 1
  google.maps.event.trigger(firstCompanyMarker, 'click')
```

However, there is one issue. The infoWindow of the default (firstCompanyMarker) marker is not showing as I need. It's crossing the top edge of the map.

I tried to move the center but there was no result.

```
 lat += 100 #or lat -=100. Anyway it does NOT work
 long += 100 # it does work but it's moving the center 
             #of the map to the left or the right and it's not what I need
 mapOptions = {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
```

Your ideas? How do I make infoWindow to be shown in the center of the map and to not cross the top edge of it?

[image]

Comment: Your coffeeScript style makes your code difficult to read. Where does function createMarker() end? are you sure that firstCompanyMarker is what you think it is?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely working.

Comment: Then you might want to try infowindow.setContent('content');  infowindow.open(map, firstCompanyMarker); but where does 'content' come from?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's just a part of the code similar to one I have.

Comment: I'm trying to help you, but you're not helping me. Suit yourself! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a the following line after "infowindow.setContent('content')"

```
map.setCenter(marker.lat-100, marker.lng-100);
```

However, this is not a real solution. From experience I can tell you that you map is very little for the standard infowindow. You have really 2 options to solve this:

1) Increase the size of the map so the default infowindow will show with the marker in the center of the map or

2) Use a custom infowindow and make it a lot smaller than the default one

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
map.setCenter(marker.lat, marker.lng- (popup.getheight/2));
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer for the sake of anyone stumbling on this.  I had the same problem and noticed that if I closed the infoWindow and clicked the marker, the infoWindow would open and pan to the correct position.  Instead of triggering a click, waiting for the `tilesloaded` event before opening the initial infoWindow was the key.

```
// Trigger click after tiles are loaded so auto-pan positions infoWindow correctly
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce( map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
    infoWindow.open( map, marker );
} );
```